# Magento download page redirect to hosting ad page

Tags: magento

I'm trying to download a magento community edition but after i access the download section, the browser redirects to 
http://magento.com/products/magento-community-edition-hosted-solution

I changed my browser from chrome to firefox,  but it keeps happening.

Then i disable the javascript and finally enter the download section, but, as you can imagine, the download button has no function.

Is that happening to you ?

I tried 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

After a search in forums i have no clue on that, so i suppose that is not a general problem. Is that possible that magento restricts the donwload based on ip address. And why?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Did you try this URL? http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Comment: I dunno.  It's working fine for me.

Comment: I uploaded it to my server.  Try this: http://www.site-sandbox.com/magento-1.8.1.0.zip

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Magento has accidentally posted content related to announcements they're going to make at Magento Imagine in 2 weeks - at least that's my take on this.

Sometime earlier today, Magento launched a new section on their site called Magento Community Edition Hosted Solution, which runs on Magento 1.9 (which isn't generally available yet) and recommends a specific hosting provider and implementing partner to build the site. It also advertises eBay integration, AheadWorks reporting extensions, etc., so this appears to be a new shift in Magento's strategy concerning Magento Community.

We've had people in the UK, Germany and the US test and they're all being redirected to this new page - http://magento.com/products/magento-community-edition-hosted-solution - when they attempt to download Magento Community.

We can only assume and hope that this is a bug, and that Magento Community downloads will still be available after Magento Community Hosted Edition launches officially, which I'm assuming will happen at Magento Imagine in 2 weeks.

As far as how to download Magento CE in the meantime - the magerun command line tool - http://magerun.net/ - still appears to be able to download Magento CE for you, so I'd recommend trying that.

UPDATE: The redirect has been removed, and the Magento CE download page has returned. Looks like this was (hopefully) a temporary mistake by the Magento web team.